# How to check whether the user is anonymous or not in Django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-authentication, anonymous-users

```
def index(request):
    the_user = request.user
```

In Django, how do I know if it's a real user or not?  I tried:

`if the_user:`  but "AnonymousUser" is there even if no one logs in.  So, it always returns true and this doesn't work.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You can check if [`request.user.is_anonymous`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous) returns `True`.

Comment: Be aware that in `views.py` you should use `request.user.is_anonymous()` since it's a function, while in templates you should use `{{user.is_anonymous}}`

Comment: Seems like in Django 1.9 it is rather `is_authenticated()`: please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

Comment: from Django 1.10, is_anonymous is no longer a method (just a property)

Comment: I must concur with Paolo Stefan, the method you want to use is `is_authenticated()`. See also http://thegarywilson.com/blog/2006/is_authenticated-vs-is_anonymous/

Comment: The current recommendation is to use `request.user.is_authenticated`, which is an attribute in Django 1.10+, the same as `is_anonymous` is now - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous. Note that if you are also using Django Guardian then these attributes won't do what you think they will - see https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html

Comment: Django docs say to use `is_authenticated` instead of `is_anonymous`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65945751/426839).

Answer (score 20):

An Alternative to

```
if user.is_anonymous():
    # user is anon user
```

is by testing to see what the id of the user object is:

```
if user.id == None:
    # user is anon user
else:
    # user is a real user
```

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymous-users

Comment: seems a bad idea. user.is_anonymous() will keep working in the new versions, user.id might not, depending on future implementations

Comment: Also, be aware that if you are using Django Guardian then the anonymous user will also have an id - see https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#configuration.

Comment: And the current recommendation as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous is to use User.is_authenticated

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. It was the first thing I tried. Seems that the "anonymous" user shows up when using user == None (and other variations).

Answer (score 11):

You should check the value of [`request.user.is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated). It will return `True` for a `User` instance and `False` for an `AnonymousUser` instance.

[One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4642607/426839) suggests using `is_anonymous` but the [django.contrib.auth documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous) says “you should prefer using `is_authenticated` to `is_anonymous`”.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue except this was on a page that the login_redirect_url was sent to. I had to put in the template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Welcome Back, {{ username }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm doing a bit of grave digging here, but a Google search brought me to this page.

If your view def requires that the user is logged in, you can implement the @login_required decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    …
```

Comment: This won't work in the stock "login" view without some customizing.

Answer (score 3):

In Django rest framework it's good idea to use permission classes to check if user is authenticated. This will apply to whole viewSet. In the simpliest form it could look like this:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
...
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`request.user.is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) as it is the preferred solution over the [`request.user.is_anonymous`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous) (the accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [is_authenticated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) and [is_anonymous](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous) with [HttpRequest.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) and [get_user(request)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#utility-functions) to check if the user is anonymous or not in Django Views as shown below. *[The doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous) recommends `is_authenticated` instead of `is_anonymous`:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render, 
from django.contrib.auth import get_user

def test(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated) # True or False
    print(request.user.is_anonymous) # True or False
    print(get_user(request).is_authenticated) # True or False
    print(get_user(request).is_anonymous) # True or False
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

And, you can check if the user is anonymous or not in Django Templates as shown below:

```
{% "index.html" %}

{{ user.is_authenticated }} {% True or False %}
{{ user.is_anonymous }} {% True or False %}
```